# How does the medical frigate land?

Tags: star-wars, return-of-the-jedi

The medical frigate is a ship that confuses me. It has to be able to land, right? But how can it physically land on the two pointy bits that are much lower than any other part of the ship? Here is what I mean:

[image: picture of the ship, showing an irregularly shaped ship that does not appear to have a way to land on a surface]

The ship is also not level — the front is lower than the back. So how can it land without damaging the ship?

Comment: Various ships in Star Wars land on repulsors only (the Naboo fighters, for example). The "bottom" of the ship is merely to stabilise the ship and to allow offloading.

Comment: @xpert Why do you assume that it is able to land? A lot of starships in the Star Wars universe are not able to land. To my knowledge, all larger star destroyers (everything bigger than the Victory-class) are not able to land, for example.

Comment: In the original trilogy I don't remember ever seeing the big ships land. Hence the need for the shuttles.

Comment: Because I am weird like that. I assume that it follows our technology and physics and i don't know that much about star wars besides the movies. I'm just not getting into the comics.

Comment: Indeed, something like that is clearly intended to only dock at a station in space.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the star destroyers dock at bespin in the air.

Comment: You'll need a couple of black plastic lifting arms; https://file.bricklink.com/3/29/29991.jpg

Comment: [The Star Destroyer at Jedha City in *Rogue One*](https://i.redd.it/5z4vutd3suxy.jpg) is an example of a large ship not needing to land.

Comment: While I agree that the same physics applies, the technology shown in Star Wars is certainly more advanced. Your assumption that it has to land is probably wrong.

Comment: Maybe it could land on a specially designed platform, similar to how the Axiom does at the end of Wall-E? See [this video](https://youtu.be/fAY8gt_wiMk?t=1m35s) around 1:35

Comment: @xpert ... `I assume that it follows our technology and physics` ... the ISS does not land either

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### All signs point to the *[EF76 Nebulon-B escort frigate](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/EF76_Nebulon-B_escort_frigate)* lacking the *capacity* to land.

The various official factbooks offer [cutaway models](https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/starwars/images/1/12/NebulonB_schem.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20081008133937) and [plan diagrams](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2hB3.jpg) for the Nebulon-B (and its successor the [Nebulon-C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMkfo.jpg)) but none mention landing gear or the substantial repulsors you'd expect to see on a ship that can land on a planet.

Additionally, none of the factbooks or RPGs give any indication of landing procedures or takeoff procedures and none of the canon films, TV shows, comics or other media show the Nebulon on a planet's surface (the ship itself being constructed at Kuat's *orbital* shipyards), nor are there any mentions of a Nebulon-class ship landing in any of the RPG books or EU novels, although there are a few glancing mentions of its in-atmosphere speed.

**It would appear that it re-supplies in space by docking with other ships and spaceports or by sending resupply shuttles to nearby planets and spends its entire lifespan in space.**

Answer (score 2):

NOT every ship in the star wars universe is built to land on a planetary surface. Some are NEVER meant to land, though some can enter an atmosphere and offload material/personnel. The Nebulon Frigate's design and ship secludes any likelihood of planetary landing
To solve that challenge they have mooring towers for large ships to offload supplies and people if they cant land. Not unlike real attempts back in the 1930's to dock airships with highrises, believing it would eliminate the need for airports and allow for point to point air transportation in cities. [image]